# True nil in select options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way of including `nil` in the options for `select`? I tried the `include_blank` option as shown below:

```
<%= select(:object, :method, {select_options}, {include_blank: t(:none)}}) %>
```

However, that does literally what it's named, adds a blank string which is not the same as `nil`. I've tried also adding a nil option to select like this:

```
<%= select(:object :method, {t(:none) => nil, select_options} %>
```

but that gives same result as above.

Of course I can handle this case in the controller but it seems very clumsy, how can I get a simple `nil` value in the select options?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set it in browsers. Nil is a literal in Ruby and not in javascript. Even if you set it, it will be posted back as "nil" string. You have to handle empty string in controller to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= select(:object, :method, {select_options}, {include_blank: true}) %>
```

Or this:

```
<%= select(:object, :method, {select_options}, {prompt: "Select an option"}) %>
```

Found here: [How do I set a blank value for an f.select form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444523/how-do-i-set-a-blank-value-for-an-f-select-form-field)

Comment: This returns a blank string, not a nil