# options_for_select Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to achieve a multi select drop down menu using `options_for_select` for this simple app but I can't get it to work.

My model search.rb

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
def search_books
    books = Book.all
    books = books.where(["market LIKE ?",market]) if market.present?
    return books
end
```

My search_controller.rb

```
   def new
     @search = Search.new    
     @markets = Book.uniq.pluck(:market)
   end
```

My search form

```
<%= form_for (@search) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :market %><br>
    <%= f.select :market, options_for_select(@markets),:multiple => true, :include_blank => true, :prompt=>'All' %>
```

My Books Table

```
create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "market"
t.string   "function"
```

............................. omitted

With these code, I can get a  single select dropdown menu but I need a multi select drop down menu.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rails api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select), the `select` method takes these arguments:

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

`:multiple => true` is an html option, so it should be the last argument of `select`

Also I think you don't need both `include_blank` and `prompt`, as they serve a similar purpose but are slightly different.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4444565/5531936) for an explanation of the difference

Therefore try this:

```
<%= f.select :market, options_for_select(@markets), :prompt=> 'Select all', :multiple => true %>
```

I'm not able to test this right now, so let me know if that works

Comment: So please can you fill in the blanks for me. I mean how should these code  ><%= f.select :market, options_for_select(@markets),:multiple => true, >:include_blank => true, :prompt=>'All' %> look like